# how to search any part of the name in datagridview

Tags: c#

how to search any part of the name in datagridview? for eg. RamGopalVarma, if i type only varma in search option it should find in gridview. When I'm using 'Contains' it showing some error. Below is my code.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString().Equals(textBox3.Text,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))       
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Selected = true; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like C.

Comment: It certainly isn't, unless there is quite a bit of macro magic happening.

Comment: "showing some error" - the error is probably really useful info to put into your question

Comment: @samuel, sorry, the above code is from c#

Comment: What about using .Contains instead of .Equals?